# php change array key to value

Tags: php, arrays

Original array is in following format:

```
        [att] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 18
                        [day_id] => 27
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 20
                        [day_id] => 32
                    )

            )
```

and array keys required to change by `day_id` as follows:

```
        [att] => Array
            (
                [27] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 18
                        [day_id] => 27
                    )

                [32] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 20
                        [day_id] => 32
                    )

            )
```

Comment: How you fetch day_id? Is this an array too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
$array['att'] = array_column($array['att'], null, 'day_id');
```